# How to get the size of datatype of an array

Tags: c++

How to get the size of datatype of an array? For Eg. `int32_t arr[10][10]` datatype is `int32_t` and it's size is `4 bytes`, similarly for `char [10][100]` datatype is `char` and it's size is `1 byte`. The reason I'm asking this question is I need to know whether data has to be swapped or not before sending via network, since datatypes of size greater than `1` need to swapped and datatypes of size equal to `1` shouldn't be swapped(in fact swapping doesn't make sense).

```
int32_t int_arr[10][10][10]; // execution should go to if part
if (sizeof(decltype(int_arr)) > 1) // this doesn't work for array type
    // swap each element and then copy to send buff
else
    // don't swap, simply copy to send buff


char char_arr[10][10]; // execution should go to else part
if (sizeof(decltype(char_arr)) > 1) // this doesn't work for array type
    // swap each element and then copy to send buff
else
    // don't swap, simply copy to send buff
```

Comment: @bloody I'm pretty sure that would give you the size of `char[10]`, which would be greater than 1.

Comment: Type type of e.g. `int_arr` in your code is `int32_t[10][10][10]`. Its size should be 4000.

Comment: an array of char is still an array of char whatever its dimensions, so you can send/receive it through a network without swap / endian problem

Comment: @bloody I responded to a comment that you have since deleted. That comment suggested using `sizeof(char_arr[0])`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Impossible, I didn't suggest anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for

```
sizeof(std::remove_all_extents_t<decltype(int_arr)>)
```

Works for non-arrays, too; when given a non-array type `T`, `std::remove_all_extents_t<T>` is simply `T`.

Comment: for compiler that support only c++11 standard use `sizeof(std::remove_all_extents<decltype(int_arr)>::type)`